# Validate RFC3339 date-time using php

Tags: php, validation, datetime, rfc3339

Any recommendations how to validate that a date-time is valid RFC3339?  I know I can convert it to unix time and then format it as valid RFC3339, but don't wish to do so and instead enforce that the correct format is provided.  http://mattallan.org/posts/rfc3339-date-time-validation/ suggests using regex, will only do as a last resort.  Thanks

Comment: @msg.  Yes, this will allow me to format as RFC3339, but how can it be  used to validate a datetime string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` has a predefined `DaTeTime::RFC3339` format constant. Since `createFromFormat` returns `false` if it can't parse the date according to the provided format, you can use that check as your validator:

```
validRFC3339Date("2018-01-29T20:36:01Z");
validRFC3339Date("2018-01-29T20:36:01+00:00");

validRFC3339Date("2018-01-22 20:36");
validRFC3339Date("2018-09-28T16:00:05.000Z");

function validRFC3339Date($date) {
    if (DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC3339, $date) === FALSE) {
        echo "$date: Invalid RFC3339\n";
    } else {
        echo "$date: Valid RFC3339\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Thanks

Comment: This is not sufficient. You must also check against the new constant `DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED`

Answer (score 2):

If you do decide to use regex, you can use the following code:

```
preg_match('/^([0-9]+)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[Tt]([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|60)(\.[0-9]+)?(([Zz])|([\+|\-]([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]))$/', $time);
```

This will return true if $time matches the regex.

Comment: Thanks Xxmarijnw,  Do you think this pattern is preferred over the one I referenced?